# Please don't double tag Google items

Tags: discussion, tags

We shouldn't be tagging items with both [google](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google) and some other tag like [google-search](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-search) or [gmail](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gmail).  [google](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google) should be used for the Google search engine.  Use the specific app name for each app.  Of course, multiple tags for multiple apps is fine.

Google should be treated like an application, not a company (unless the question is specifically about the company, which leads to a little confusion, but probably not too much).  You wouldn't use a [microsoft](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/microsoft) tag on an Excel question.

You can see from most of the cases in Super User how it should work, [like so](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/gmail).

Comment: I agree that items should not be tagged with both `google` and `google-search`, actually I think that instead of using `google` should be used other tags like `google-account` for general Google sign in and account items , `google-inc` for Google Incorporated is Google as a company could be on-topic in Web Applications.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I agree that we need to remove the duplicate tagging. I think `[google-search]` should be used for Google searches though. This way it isn't ambiguous with the company Google.

I have already changed those tagged with `[google]` `[search]` to `[google-search]`, so I would ask that this convention be followed for now. If the community wants to change it later on to something like `[google]`, we would then be able to easily rename all these tags effortlessly using the tag rename feature (rather than having to go one by one on all the `[google]` tags and figuring out if they are about the company or about search).

Comment: That sounds fine, thanks for the input.

Comment: The reason I figured on just `google` for the search engine, is because most new people coming here for an answer are only going to think of that, since Google only refers to it by their name (on the site itself).

Comment: New people cannot create new tag names, so Senseful's suggestion is just fine.  New people would start typing "goog[...]" and would just need to choose the best fit (which would be `[google-search]`.  We *should* make sure that `[google-search]` is always one of the suggestions (top 6), though.  (By the way, I see the google tag is still alive and well in 2013 (over 700 copies of it), so this 3-year-old question seems still on-topic.)

Answer (score 4):

Another double tag that is frequently used and shouldn't be in most cases is:
`google-drive` `google-documents`.

Cases that shouldn't include both tags.
when the question is about Google Documents text processing features.
...

Cases that could include both tags:
when the question Google Documents properties displayed in Google Drive
...

Comment: Part of the issue there is that Google Drive was originally Google Docs. Also, questions about a more than one of Documents/Spreadsheets/Presentations are appropriately tagged 'google-drive'.

Comment: @AI E: At this time Google documents, spreadsheets and presentations have their own app: Docs, Sheets, and Slides respectively, so I think that not all questions about two or more Google Editors require the `google-drive` tag. I.E. copy & paste between this apps.

Answer (score 2):

Looking for the top 20 tags on Web Application on the tags page I found that [google](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google) have 38 questions this year. As most of these questions were "double-tagged" so I removed [google](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google) from many of them (also I tried to fix other problems, vote to close, post a comment, etc.)

One curious finding was a question about Windows Server that only had [google](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google) and was not anyway related to Google services.