# [apple] tag redundant?

Tags: discussion, tags

To me, it seems like the [apple] tag is redundant. What do you guys think?

Comment: On WebApps? . .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There can be posts that refer to Google the company or Apple the company.  See [this post](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/540/please-dont-double-tag-google-items) for some discussion on Google tags (with you).

**EDIT:**  None of those questions needed that tag, so I cleaned them up.

Answer (score 0):

My opinion on this is the same for [google].  At least Google deals with web applications more than Apple.  Personally, I'd close the question regarding Apple Calendar as that seems like a SU question, and then [apple] can safely be removed from the other 3 questions.